# Single event in React Redux app that integrates legacy library

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React app using Redux to handle the overall state of the app that also integrates some legacy Javascript library to present a specific viewer (on a canvas). The legacy library manages for the viewer its own state (and I don't have access to it). I now have the case that one of my components need to trigger an event on the viewer in another component (e.g. reset the viewer using the legacy library).

I can think of two solutions:

1. Do a Redux state change (e.g. `{reset: true}`) that is provided to the viewer component via props. And after the viewer component reseted the viewer, it directly resets the state itself (e.g. `{reset: false}).
2. Bypass Redux and use some kind of [PubSub](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS) pattern for those components to communicate directly to each other without any Redux state change.

Is there recommended way? What are the advantages/disadvantages? One downside of option 1 seems that it triggers a re-render when the state is updated the second time (`{reset: false}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way i have come up is by specifying the time at which it got reset.
If the time changes this will trigger a re-render.

on dispatch(reset())

Action:

```
reset(){
  return({
   type:constant.RE_RENDER,
   payload: new Date().getTime()
  })
}
```

STORE:

```
if(state.reset < action.payload){
  return {
   reset: action.payload
  }
}
```

The view will get updated only once. Using another pub-sub system will add undue complications and bypassing redux pattern is not recommended.

Comment: Good idea. I like that.